# What is the best way to extract a numerical date from Ruby default date/time output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to retrieve the date which is 24 hours ago.

```
time = Time.now.to_time - 24.hours
time.to_date
=> Wed, 05 Oct 2022
```

I require it in the following format:

```
2022-10-05
```

Having read the Ruby time docs, and various questions here, I still haven't figured out the must succinct and clean way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a Date object it is simply

```
puts Date.today - 1  # => 2022-10-05
```

With a  Time Object , the `-` method subtracts seconds. So:

```
Time.now - 24*60*60
```

All this works without Rails.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebuild any value with specific date methods :

```
Time.now.day 
=> 6

Time.now.month
=> 10

Time.now.year
=> 2022
```

So doing something like

```
formatted_date = "#{time.year}-#{time.month}-#{time.day}"
```

should work

Also you can check `strftime()` method documented here : https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime. It seems your format is included in ISO8601 formats : `time.strftime("%F")`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```rb
Date.yesterday.to_s #=> "2022-10-5"
```